# Typescript definition for typeof keyof T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a system which can work with different "state" objects, an example instance of such a state object could be:

```js
interface MyState {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  things: string[];
}
```

I also have a class to interact with various state implementations

```js
class StateManager<T> {

  state: T;

  pick(field: keyof T) {
    return this.state[field];
  }
}
```

I would like to type hint the exact output of `pick`, at the moment I am getting a union of all possible types. `string | number | string[]`

Is there something like

```
pick<K extends keyof T>(field: keyof T): typeof K
```

Such that `pick('name')` would be `string` and `pick('age')` is `number`